# how is the container component

Tags: java, swing, focus

i have an application with two main panel LEFT and RIGHT
when a component got focus i want to know 
how is the container that holds that component (LEFT or RIGHT) 
the component can be inside some other panel's ,
but eventually sits inside the LEFT or RIGHT panel

is there a more simple way to know who is the container without 
running in loop on get parent each time a component got focus

thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think i got it

```
pnla.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
pnla.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new JTPCScreenMainFocusTraversalPolicy());

pnlb.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
pnlb.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new JTPCScreenOptionsFocusTraversalPolicy());
```

and when component focused i ask for

```
component.getFocusCycleRootAncestor() instance of PNL_A
```

thanks